# sql code is not working in phpmyadmin using mac?

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

My teacher provided me with this sql code, and I logged in as root into phpmyadmin, added a database called webstore, and then tried to add this code and it's giving me errors. Is there anyone who can tell me what could be causing the errors? I am using a Mac, so I'm not sure if that makes any difference, I can give you a link to dropbox with additional information if necessary.

This is the dropbox link with the code provided (Webstore.sql): https://www.dropbox.com/sh/usfmbeyxqd2q1g5/AADoLFbsz8cL30EC76d60i40a?dl=0

Also, the zip file contains images of the errors I was receiving. PLEASE HELP!!

The SQL statement the error occurs on is

```
CREATE TABLE Shopping_Cart (
  CustID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ProdID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NumOfItems INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CustID, ProdID)
  CONSTRAINT FK_Cust FOREIGN KEY FK_Cat (CustID) 
    REFERENCES Customers (CustID)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT FK_Prod FOREIGN KEY FK_Prod (ProdID) 
    REFERENCES Products (ProdID)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);
```

The error reads

> 1. A comma or closing bracket was expected. (near "CONSTRAINT" at position 153)
> 2. Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "CustID" at position 192)
> 3. Unrecognised statement type. (near "REFERENCES" at position 206)

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors.

Comment: It won't let me include all of it because their are links, and it says new users can't have more than two. :(

Comment: If you declare something NOT NULL you must also specify a DEFAULT

Comment: @JayBlanchard Good point also. I might suggest OP asks their teacher to actually check the code since it appears they hand wrote it and never tested it.

Comment: My teacher sucks, he doesn't get back to his students ever. I e-mailed him over a week ago about this, and the project is due this sunday. And the code works for students on windows...

Answer (score 0):

Your `PRIMARY KEY` line needs a comma after it before the `CONSTRAINT`.

```
CREATE TABLE Shopping_Cart (
  CustID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ProdID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NumOfItems INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CustID, ProdID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Cust FOREIGN KEY FK_Cat (CustID) 
    REFERENCES Customers (CustID)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT FK_Prod FOREIGN KEY FK_Prod (ProdID) 
    REFERENCES Products (ProdID)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);
```

**Edit**

It turns out there were a lot of problems with the SQL. The tables were created in the wrong order and the data types were wrong. Here is a rewritten version that I have tested out:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS WebStore;
CREATE DATABASE WebStore;
USE WebStore;

CREATE TABLE Categories (
    CatID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Descr VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    IconURL VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CatID)
);

CREATE TABLE Products (
    ProdID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Category INTEGER UNSIGNED,
    Descr VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    Price FLOAT NOT NULL,
    Stock INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    IconURL VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ProdID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Cat FOREIGN KEY FK_Cat (Category)
        REFERENCES Categories (CatID)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);

INSERT INTO Categories VALUES(null,"Laptops","Small computers you can carry","http://localhost/images/laptop.jpg");
SET @laptops := LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO Categories VALUES(null,"Desktops","Big computers you cannot carry","http://localhost/images/desktop.jpg");
SET @desktops := LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO Categories VALUES(null,"Tablets"," Flat things you lose frequently","http://localhost/images/tablet.jpg");
SET @tablets := LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO Products VALUES(null,"DULL 1200",@desktops,"A big dull machine",1290.99,23,"http://localhost/images/dull1200.jpg");
INSERT INTO Products VALUES(null,"8P Totalo",@desktops,"Almost as big as the DULL",990.99,2,"http://localhost/images/8ptotalo.jpg");
INSERT INTO Products VALUES(null,"LaNuveau Bingster",@desktops,"Comes in blue and red",690.99,12,"http://localhost/images/lanuveaubingster.jpg");

INSERT INTO Products VALUES(null,"DULL 122",@laptops,"Small, portable and useless",422.99,4,"http://localhost/images/dull122.jpg");
INSERT INTO Products VALUES(null,"8P Tootsie",@laptops,"Sticky and too heavy",559.99,12,"http://localhost/images/8ptootsie.jpg");
INSERT INTO Products VALUES(null,"LaNuveau Shoobie XT",@laptops,"Weighs a ton but looks sharp",1690.99,122,"http://localhost/images/lanuveaushoobiext.jpg");

INSERT INTO Products VALUES(null,"Motor Roller 12",@tablets,"The only one with a oval screen",422.99,4,"http://localhost/images/mr12.jpg");
INSERT INTO Products VALUES(null,"SamSings OffKey",@tablets,"Needs duct tape to run",559.99,2,"http://localhost/images/samsingsOK.jpg");
INSERT INTO Products VALUES(null,"jPet 12",@tablets,"The first that kinda sorta works",16290.99,722,"http://localhost/images/jpet12.jpg");

CREATE TABLE Customers (
    CustID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FirstName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Address VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    City VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    State VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Zip VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CustID)
);

INSERT INTO Customers VALUES(null,"Gerald","Bostock","1234 TAAB Drive","St. Cleve","FL","12345");
INSERT INTO Customers VALUES(null,"Suzy","Creamcheese","8722 Zappa Road","Paris","TX","75460");

CREATE TABLE Shopping_Cart (
    CustID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ProdID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    NumOfItems INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CustID, ProdID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Cust FOREIGN KEY FK_Cat (CustID) 
        REFERENCES Customers (CustID)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Prod FOREIGN KEY FK_Prod (ProdID) 
        REFERENCES Products (ProdID)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);

INSERT INTO Shopping_Cart VALUES("1","4","2");
INSERT INTO Shopping_Cart VALUES("1","9","1");
```

Comment: After adding comma:
SQL query:


CREATE TABLE Shopping_Cart (
  CustID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ProdID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NumOfItems INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CustID, ProdID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Cust FOREIGN KEY FK_Cat (CustID) 
    REFERENCES Customers (CustID)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT FK_Prod FOREIGN KEY FK_Prod (ProdID) 
    REFERENCES Products (ProdID)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)

MySQL said: Documentation

#1005 - Can't create table `webstore`.`shopping_cart` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)

Comment: @katracho7 Your teacher sounds like an idiot. I would be surprised if the code he wrote works on any operating system, but in any case I've updated my answer with a completely rewritten version that should fix the other problems you were having.

Comment: Dude you are the man, I really appreciate all the help. It wasn't until the night it was due he had to make this Final Project optional. It was worth a minuscule fraction of what it was supposed to, and I was the only one who got it done.